# MySQLSyntaxErrorException but no clue why

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception, jdbc

```
public void verhoogAantalGewonnenSpellen(Speler speler, Spel spel){

    try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectie.JDBC_URL)){
        PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE ID222177_g69.Speler SET ? = ? + 1 WHERE spelernaam = ?");

        query.setString(1, "aantalGewonnen" + spel.getMoeilijkheidsgraad());
        query.setString(2, "aantalGewonnen" + spel.getMoeilijkheidsgraad());
        query.setString(3, speler.getNaam());
        query.executeUpdate();

    } catch(SQLException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Running this code gives me the following error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''aantalGewonnenMakkelijk' = 'aantalGewonnenMakkelijk' + 1 WHERE spelernaam = 'ObamaJohansson'

The table `Speler` has the following columns:

```
spelernaam((VARCHAR(45)PK, NN)
wachtwoord((VARCHAR(45))NN)
aantalGewonnenMakkelijk(INT(11))
aantalGewonnenNormaal(INT(11)
aantalGewonnenMoeilijk(INT(11).
```

I have been struggling with this exception for a couple hours and I just can't seem to figure it out... Can anybody please help me?

Comment: I don't believe you can use a prepared statement to dynamically replace a column name. `SET ? = ?` likely won't work as you are generating the following SQL statement: `UPDATE ID222177_g69.Speler SET 'aantalGewonnenMakkelijk' = 'aantalGewonnenMakkelijk'  + 1 WHERE spelernaam = 'ObamaJohansson'`

Comment: You have two problems: 1) you can't replace "column names" (like ""aantalGewonnen"), just column *values*.  2) Use "setString()" for *String* values ... and use "setInt()" for *integer* values.

Comment: @paulsm4 I think you have wronged me with your down-vote ;) read both answers above and check again the logic

Answer (score 1):

coukd be you need  setInt instead of setString

```
    query.setInt(1, aantalGewonnen + spel.getMoeilijkheidsgraad());
    query.setInt(2, aantalGewonnen + spel.getMoeilijkheidsgraad());
```

and as suggested  by YCF_L  you shuold use column name and  not var is set clause  eg:

```
   UPDATE ID222177_g69.Speler SET your_column_name= you_column_name + 1 
   WHERE spelernaam = ?
```

or

```
  UPDATE ID222177_g69.Speler SET your_column_name= ? 
   WHERE spelernaam = ?
```

Comment: Is that logic to use `.. SET 5 = 5 + 1` ? :) I think the correct logic is above @scaisEdge

Comment: I. have not evalueted the  "logic"  .. i have just showed  the part that produce the error  :.  (the error is related  to a string  in a numeric field )  .. obviuosly you comment is correct  ..  but .. as said before  .. my code is just for binding  .. so you should suggest this to the OP ..

Comment: anyway  .. asnwer  updated  with the YCF_L suggestion  too

Comment: aantalGewonnen + spelGetMoeilijkheidsgraad() returns a String, so it should definitly be setString(). Applying your suggestion returns the same error.

Comment: if you look at  the code gereated  by your code   .. you can see  tha you have column name  as  quoted  string  (generated  by binding )  .. this is not allowed .. you should not assign column name as  string but assing only the values  as  a proper result ( i assumed  that adding + 1 mean you have an integer) so you should also use the code suggested  for proper updated

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the name of the column like you do instead you can use this way to concatenate the query and the name of the column :

```
String colName = "aantalGewonnen" + spel.getMoeilijkheidsgraad();
String sql = String.format(
        "UPDATE ID222177_g69.Speler SET %s = %s + 1 WHERE spelernaam = ?",
        colName, colName
);
```

This will gives you :

```
UPDATE ID222177_g69.Speler 
SET aantalGewonnenSomeName = aantalGewonnenSomeName + 1 
WHERE spelernaam = ?
```

Then create the prepared statement like this :

```
PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
query.setString(1, speler.getNaam());
```

I assume that `"aantalGewonnen" + spel.getMoeilijkheidsgraad()` gives you the name of the column.

---

**Important**

But this way is not enough secure, you have to check if the name is correct or not, else it can cause another Syntax error or SQL Injection.

Comment: Using `String.format()` and `'%s` is legal ... but you should prefer using `?` instead.  Doing otherwise defeats the whole purpose of having a prepared statement :(

Comment: @paulsm4 you can't use `?` to set the name of the column, and I was totally clear in my Important section

Comment: You might be up to something @YCF_L, i'm going to try it out